# fill in password based on var shell script

Tags: shell

I'm working on a shell script where it zips up a file then uploads it to a server i have.

So far i have it so it asks for the server password and then keeps that variable. After it does that the script zips up a folder with a bunch of files in it. Then it dose the "scp" command to send it to my server.

Now, this is where i need help... I want it to fill in the password that was provided earlier in the script when it asks for the server password. I'm sure your asking "why doesn't just put in the password when the "scp" command asks for it. The reason being is that the file i have is going to be large, and i dont want to sit around and watch it zip up. So thats why i provide the password early on.

### here are the steps:

1) user provides server password which is saved as the variable "password"

2) the script zips up the file

3) the script sends the file to the server (when i run this part in the script it asks for the password. i have to put in the password variable here.)

Any ideas on how to do this? thanks so much, will,

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is flawed, for several reasons, both security-related and technical.

What you should do is to create a "null" SSH session in the background that generates a master connection (see the `ControlPath` and `ControlMaster` options in the `ssh_config(5)` man page). Using the same control settings for the subsequent SCP operation will use this connection without having to ask for the password. Don't forget to kill the null session once the script is done.

Comment: it's ok tho, because it's a personal script and it wont be distributed.